# There was an issue communication with the cmd server.Check to make sure you have the latest version of cmd installed

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I have upgrade a solution which was developed in Exts JS 4 with sencha architect 3 to Exts JS 5 using sencha architech 3.1.After upgrading ,i am getting following error.

"There was an issue communication with the cmd server.Check to make sure you have the latest version of cmd installed."

Could someone help me????

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I resolved it by running the sencha CMD server. 
I was able to start it up using the instructions from: http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/use-the-sencha-cmd-webserver/#.VHGF5dKUdAo.

I imagine there is more info on this in the Sencha documentation but this seemed to make the error go away for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to download and install the Java JDK form Oracle.

Java SE Development Kit 8

Mine is running on a Mac OS X Yosemite.
And i was using Sencha Architect 3.2